# How do I fix this error for reticulate in Rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, reticulate

I searched Stack Overflow for fixes to this error and will put all the things that I have tried below that did not solve the issue. I have not had an issue on other computers but for some reason, reticulate does not want to work for me.

```
install.packages('reticulate')
```

> WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently
> installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of
> Rtools before proceeding:
>
> https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/ Installing package into
> ‘C:/Users/zcantrell/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’ (as ‘lib’ is
> unspecified) also installing the dependencies ‘Rcpp’, ‘RcppTOML’,
> ‘jsonlite’, ‘png’, ‘rappdirs’
>
> Warning in install.packages :   unable to access index for repository
> https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3:   cannot open URL
> 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/PACKAGES' Packages
> which are only available in source form, and may need compilation of
> C/C++/Fortran: ‘Rcpp’   ‘RcppTOML’ ‘jsonlite’ ‘png’ ‘rappdirs’
> ‘reticulate’   These will not be installed

Things I have tried

```
install.packages('Rtools')
pack <- c('Rccp', 'RccpTOML', 'jsonlite', 'jsonlite', 'png', 'rappdirs')
install.packages(pack)
install.packages('reticulate', type = 'source')
```

Comment: Can you explain how your question is related to `python` which is one of tage you have used?

Comment: It looks like you are using R version 3.3 which is very old now. I strongly suggest you updated your R to a more current version. Compiled versions of packages for older versions of R are not available on CRAN.

Comment: @Daweo I appreciate you looking. It was the combination of Rstudio, R, reticulate, and python that was the tag. Reticulate is an R package where you can run python along with R in Rstudio. I see where you could get confused with the tag "python" so I deleted it.

Comment: This worked, Case is closed. Thanks!